# Hadoop 2.7.3 not running in offline mode

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, hadoop2.7.3

I am running hadoop 2.7.3 single node on ubuntu 16.04... But its not
    working in offline mode.. Can the problem be in /etc/hosts file as I
    tried to edit it, to make it a multi node cluster...

Answer (score 0):

Try performing the steps as shown in the video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuzL60VEw0o

Let me know if this helps. Also ensure you comment the below line from /etc/hosts

127.0.1.1 xxxxx

If this doesn't help, share the logs to understand the root cause of the problem.

Hope this helps !!! Cheers !!!

Comment: A link to a video is not a good answer. Please make your answer useful even without the link.